# How exactly do you configure the base href for flutter web +github pages? [blank page issue]

Tags: html, flutter, dart, github, web

Ok, so my first web app, heres the step to do it,
created a flutter project,
it already contained a `web` folder, first ran the project in chrome debug, worked fine,
next uploaded to github just the project folder `web` and not the whole project. did the necessary steps to get the flutter page. now when i run it, it gives me blank page on github where as its fine in local machine.

my questions are

1. do i need to upload the whole project or uploading just the web folder is fine?
2. i am told to edit `base href` but unsure where exactly and how do i edit it ?

this is the `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="air_duty_roster">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>air_duty_roster</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the link.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution so far

1. create a repo with this extension `username/project_name.github.io`
2. run the command `flutter build web`
3. upload the files under build/web to github project
4. go to the file `index.html` and completely remove  `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">`
5. wait for a few minutes
6. Done

Answer (score 0):

Build the application before deploying.

```
flutter build web
```

See [Building the app for release](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#building-the-app-for-release)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build using comand:

```dart
flutter build web --base-href='/roster/'
```

Sometimes github pages are not lightning fast. You need to wait some time for the changes to take effect after your deploy.